# Why can't I access an initialized class member's method in constructor?

Tags: c++, oop, arduino

I am quite new to C++ and I am attempting to create a controller for an LCD I am using with an Arduino. I am having difficulty using the library required to interact with the LCD.

In my LCD class, I have initialized a LiquidCrystal_I2C member which happens to be a class. In the constructor for LCD, I have provided an initialization list for said member which should appropriately create the object. The problem is when I attempt to access one of its methods (init) it doesn't work. This code doesn't cause any compiler issues but simply has no effect. A simplified source and header file have been provided below.

```
/* lcd.h */

#include "LiquidCrystal_I2C.h"

class LCD {
    private:
        LiquidCrystal_I2C controller;

    public:
        LCD(long unsigned timeout_time = 10000, int static_page_num = 0); // Constructor
};
```

```
/* lcd.c */

LCD::LCD(long unsigned timeout_time, int static_page_num) : controller(0x27, 16, 2) {
    this->active = false;
    this->start_time = 0;
    this->active_time = 0;
    this->timeout_time = timeout_time;

    this->static_page_num = static_page_num;
    this->num_pages = 0;
    this->current_page = 0;
    this->current_content = "";

    this->controller.init(); // Doesn't work
}
```

The problematic code in question, `this->controller.init()`, with the obvious replacement of this with a reference works after the LCD class is constructed. The init function is meant to initialize the LCD so that it has its backlight turned on and printed too. This doesn't happen when the function is called in the constructor.

The TrackerLCD class, which is a subclass of LCD, is declared in the global scope in the main file.

```
TrackerLCD lcd;
```

```
/* TrackerLCD.c */

TrackerLCD::TrackerLCD(long unsigned timeout_time) : LCD(timeout_time, 1) {
    LCD_Page * reset_page = new LCD_Page("Reset");
    LCD_Page * animal_count_page = new LCD_Page("Total: 0");

    this->add_page(reset_page);
    this->add_page(animal_count_page);
}
```

```
/* TrackerLCD.h */

#include "lcd.h"

class TrackerLCD : public LCD {
    public:
        TrackerLCD(long unsigned timeout_time = 10000);
        void display_reset();
        void display_animal_count(int animal_count);
};
```

Why is this? I have used this pattern before with my own classes and it works fine.

It is something to do with the library? The init function is provided below.

```
void LiquidCrystal_I2C::init(){
    init_priv();
}

void LiquidCrystal_I2C::init_priv()
{
    Wire.begin();
    _displayfunction = LCD_4BITMODE | LCD_1LINE | LCD_5x8DOTS;
    begin(_cols, _rows);  
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] and clarify what you mean by `"it doesn't work"`.  What does `LiquidCrystal_I2C::init` do?  Please show the relevant code.

Comment: @G.M. Sorry about that. I have provided an example of the concept I'm trying to apply working. The code for init. And an explanation of what init does.

Comment: did you use a debugger or some `cout`s to see that `init_priv` is actually called when the constructor of `LCD` is executed? If yes, most of the code you posted is not that relevant, but the problem is in `init_priv`

Comment: I think that both `this->controller.init();` and the library code `init()` are OK. I expect the problem to be with the way you use your `LCD` class. Show the code where the object of your `LCD` class is created and used. For comparison you can also show the piece of code where you used `LiquidCrystal_I2C` outside your class and it worked.

Comment: Please remove the working MRE, you need to only provide a [mre] of the code which does not work (but which you think should work).

Comment: Your code is still neither complete (what happens in `"LiquidCrystal_I2C.h"`?), nor minimal. Copy everything relevant into a single file and remove all irrelevant lines.

Comment: @chtz I wouldn't know what is relevant in "LiquidCrystal_I2C.h" file beyond the init and init_priv functions I've already provided. I'm sorry I'm not being very helpful but I'm really struggling to articulate and present the problem I've experiencing beyond what I've done.

Comment: Perhaps it just doesn't like `init()` being called "that early". You can make a simple test: Instead of the global `TrackerLCD lcd;` - make a function: `TrackerLCD& lcd() { static TrackerLCD instance; return instance; }` and in all places where you now use `lcd`, use `lcd()` instead. That should be a drop-in replacement that delays construction, and with that, `init()`, until the first use of `lcd()`.

Comment: you can find out what is relevant by creating a whole new project to which you add code until it reproduces the problem. Alternatively you can remove code from your current problem in steps until the problem is gone, then go one step back to have a minimal example that reproduces your problem. (often during this process you find the problem and solution by yourself, if not you have something that you can post here)

Comment: You are not even saying how "it doesn't work". It may be something trivial like the method is marked as `private` ...